# How to move database from Db2/Linux/System-z to Db2/Linux/Intel

Tags: db2, db2-luw

our company has decided to migrate database:

- from source Db2 Enterprise Server Edition v11.1 fixpack 5 on Linux/System-z (this is still Linux/Unix/Windows type of database despite running on System-z mainfraime)
- to Db2 Enterprise Edition v11.1 fixpack 5 on x86_64 (Intel/AMD).

Linux/System-z is big endian system and Linux/x86_64 is little endian system. There is no backup/restore option between bin/little endian Linux system.

The other option that I have read a lot about is combination of: db2look/db2move and a plenty of manual tasks. This seems pretty dangerous operation, because one little mistake and something may go terrible wrong when applications start using database on target system.

On PostgreSQL system there is build-in pg_dump tool. With this tool one single command dumps whole database (all objects: create database, create table, triggers, foreign keys, primary keys, etc including all of the data) into one single huge file, that can be easily transferred   to target system and then one single command is executed on target system to get the database up and running. There are no manual interventions, tricks, procedures etc. Just two commands, one on source and one on target system. Is there something similar on Db2?

Is there any other way to move database between two Linux/endian systems except db2look/db2move? Some sophisticated tool or something?

Regards

Comment: You can use federation between them (and thus load from cursor to populate the tables). That's probably the fastest way.  You can also use slow export to IXF on z/linux,  and load from ixf to x64/linux.

Comment: db2look will under certain circumstances generate objects in the wrong order. I did not find a tool that could do a migration for me, so I wrote one. It is by no means complete, but it should be fairly easy to extend to features that I did not need. You can have a look at https://github.com/lelle1234/Db2Utils/blob/master/DBParser/ and see if it fit your needs

Answer (score 1):

Check IBM Data Movement Tool. Link https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/data/library/techarticle/dm-0906datamovement/

Comment: Today I tested this tool. I created simple database on db2/zLinux and few objects in it (tables, PK, FK,...) and moved them using this tool to db2/x86_64 and I see at least three problems: a) foreign keys are not created, b) triggers are not created and c) if table is created with timestamp column and "generated always" definition (most of our tables) tables are not created on target database. I have only tested few of objects and having 3 problems already. I don't know if I am doing something wrong or this tool is not really perfect tool for migrations.

Comment: I used tool 7 years ago to migrate from "DB2 for i" to DB LUW.  I was able to migrate FK, triggers, etc. I have not tried migrating from DB2/zLinux.

Comment: I have investigated more. IBM Data Movement Tool was last updated in 2010. Currently suggested successor is "IBM Harmony Profiler". I installed it and to my surprise there is no option to migrate from DB2 LUW to DB2 LUW. Only available migrations are Oracle to Db2, Netezza to Db2 and Teradata to Db2.

Answer (score 0):

Well, there's [Lift](https://www.ibm.com/ca-en/cloud/lift) but it still runs the same commands under the hood. You can't expect the migration of a database between platforms to be a single click process in any event. You shouldn't compare it with the usual backup/restore.

The risk of "one little mistake and something may go terrible wrong" should be taken care of by your usual regression testing process, which you undoubtedly have in place.